# How to read XML child node element attributes in each iteration c#?

Tags: c#, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Checkplan>
  <masters>   
    <sections>
      <characteristics>
        <characterstic name="xxx1">
        </characterstic>
        <characterstic name="xxx2">
        </characterstic>
        <image id="xxx"></image>
      </characteristics>
    </sections>    
    <sections>
      <characteristics>
        <characterstic name="yyy1">
        </characterstic>
        <characterstic name="yyy2">
        </characterstic>
        <image id="yyy"></image>
      </characteristics>
    </sections>   

  </masters>
</Checkplan>
```

Image id xxx is common for xxx1 and xxx2 .
Image id yyy is common for yyy1 and yyy2 so i need to loop through only xxx related attributes from first iteration then i have 
to read yyy reated in next iteration .
Iteration should run for each section .

```
 XmlNodeList dataNodes = xml.SelectNodes("//Section");
                foreach (XmlNode node in dataNodes)
                {

                    foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
                    {


                        foreach (XmlNode childNode2 in childNode.ChildNodes)
                        {

                            FeatureName = childNode2.Attributes["Name"].Value;
                            LSL = Convert.ToInt32(childNode2.Attributes["LSL"].Value);
                            USL = Convert.ToInt32(childNode2.Attributes["USL"].Value);

                        }
                    }
                    if (!FeaturesCollection.ContainsKey(FeatureName))
                    {

                        FeaturesCollection.Add(FeatureName, new Features { m_Name = FeatureName, m_LSL = LSL, m_USL = USL, m_ImageID = imageid });
                    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx)? SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: I have to read sections >characterstics>characterstic attribute name ,image id then i have to come out of loop and do same thing for others sections.

Comment: Exactly. *You* have to. So I ask again, what have you tried?

Comment: I have added c# code snapshots  what i have tried please see it

Comment: @Kingcobra - your code doesn't seem to match your XML.  There are no `"LSL"` or `"USL"` attributes in the XML, and no element named `<Section>`.  Can you share a real example of what you have tried so far -- i.e. a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq.  You left an 'i' out of characteristic in the xml file.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("characteristics").Select(x => new {
                id = (string)x.Element("image").Attribute("id"),
                characteristics = x.Elements("characteristic").ToList().Select(y => (string)y.Attribute("name")).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<State>
  <District>
    <Town>
      <City>
        <Village>
          <Person Name="xxxx1"/>
          <Person Name="xxxx2"/>
        </Village>
        <Village>
          <Person Name="yyy1"/>
          <Person Name="yyy2"/>
        </Village>      </City>    </Town>  </District></State>
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Filepath);
var Res = from r in doc.Descendants("State").Descendants("District").Descendants("Town").Descendants("City").Descendants("Village")
select new{Pname = r.Element("Person")Value};Need person details

Comment: its working but it reads only image id its not reading characterstic name="xxx1"

Comment: It is an Attribute not an Element : var Res = from r in doc.Descendants‌​("Person") select new{Pname = (string)r.Attribute("Name")};